# Object oriented programming:

Tags: c++, oop

i need to write a program with is fully oop.(Domain, Repository, Controller, UI(TUI)) But i have some issues with creating the link between my menu > controller > repo functions. How should i create the constructor of the controller? i have an example but i dont get much from it, could anyone  explain me this constructor?

```
class ConsoleUI {
public:
    ConsoleUI(MusicStore* store) : musicStore(store) {}
    void run();

private:
    MusicStore* musicStore;

    void showMenu();
    int readOption();
           .
           .
           .
    void showMenu();
    int readOption();

    void printBestSoldAlbums();
};
```

Comment: Please, *do* use proper indenting. Only one line in your code is actually a "constructor", as I hope you are aware. It sets the (member) variable `musicStore` to the constructor parameter `store`, nothing more. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class has constructor with one argument - a pointer to `MusicStore` object.
Only thing it does - sets `musicStore` member to passed argument.

Comment: thanks, for the prompt answere